# The right padding disappears when the container is scrollable

Tags: html, css

Well, the title is self-explanatory. Thanks in advance :)

```css
.parent {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 120px;
  height: 150px;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 20px;
}

.child {
  background-color: red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Try running the code snippet, and you'll see the parent's right padding is not visible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have given **two solutions**.

*1* - Use **margin** for the `.child` instead of **padding** the `.parent`.

Add these rules for `.child`:

```
margin: 20px;
display: inline-block;
```

And remove `padding: 20px` out of `.parent`.

```css
.parent {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 120px;
  height: 150px;
  overflow: auto;
  /*padding: 20px;*/
}

.child {
  background-color: red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
  </div>
</div>
```

*2* - Add `position: relative` for `.child`. Add a set of rules with pseudo-class `:after` for `.child`:

```
.child:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  right: -20px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 1px;
}
```

```css
.parent {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 120px;
  height: 150px;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 20px;
}

.child {
  background-color: red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
}

.child:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  right: -20px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Seems like the second solution suits my needs. I also need to add `margin: auto` to the child.

Comment: @Ukasha, Although I thought you would choose the first solution, lol. Why would you add `margin: auto`?

Comment: Sometimes, the width or height of the parent far exceeds its child. If so, I want the child to be positioned in the middle of the parent.

Comment: @Ukasha, better use `display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center;` for `.parent`. `margin: auto` will not center the height.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are explicitly setting the width of the `child` element, which is the larger than `parent`, it overflows outside of parent. You can set the child to a percentage which will take up a percentage of the parent while respecting the padding of `parent`.

```css
.parent {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 120px;
  height: 150px;
  overflow: auto;
  /* padding: 20px; */
  margin: 20px;
}

.child {
  background-color: red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It seems to me, but there should be a horizontal scroll.

Comment: Why did you set `margin: 20px` in the `.parent`? This rule is not helpful. And it is not in the default code.